# MongoDB Where Clause NOT Working with $gt $lt

Tags: mongodb

this is my query statement,

```
{ "customerId" : { "$in" : ["1372727786178519042"]}, 
    "screenTime" : { "$gte" : "2022-08-25 00:00:00", "$lte" : "2023-08-25 23:59:59"}, 
    "$and" : [{ "itemInfos.itemValue" : { "$lt" : 180}, "itemInfos.itemCode" : "height"}]}
```

but find $gt 180 data,like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e542B.png)

someboby can tell me why ?

Comment: Please don't use images for code/errors/data/tracebacks/etc. - just paste them into a code block.

Comment: You probably want to use `"$elemMatch"`, like this [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1BPue_k2dkR).